# How to derive the expiry value based on the value of the field in spring couchbase document

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-8, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

Spring data couchbase has @document annotations which has expiry and expiryexpression attributes.

How to read the value dynamically from one of the field in the document and set to the expiry/expiryexpression in spring boot data couchbase?

Answer (score 1):

The expiration of a document is stored in the "meta" part of the document. You can read more about it here:
https://blog.couchbase.com/how-to-manage-ttl-with-couchbase-n1ql/

If you load the document using the SDK, you can read it directly:

```
bucket.defaultCollection().get("youDocumentID").expiryTime();
bucket.defaultCollection().get("youDocumentID").expiry()
```